# pandas merge/rearrange/sum single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
    latitude    longitude   d1  d2  ar  merge_time
0   15  10.0    12/1/1981 0:00  12/4/1981 3:00  2.317681391 1981-12-04 04:00:00
1   15  10.1    12/1/1981 0:00  12/1/1981 3:00  2.293604127 1981-12-01 04:00:00
2   15  10.2    12/1/1981 0:00  12/1/1981 2:00  2.264552161 1981-12-01 03:00:00
3   15  10.3    12/1/1981 0:00  12/4/1981 2:00  2.278556423 1981-12-04 03:00:00
4   15  10.1    12/1/1981 4:00  12/1/1981 22:00 2.168275766 1981-12-01 23:00:00
5   15  10.2    12/1/1981 3:00  12/1/1981 21:00 2.114636628 1981-12-01 22:00:00
6   15  10.4    12/1/1981 0:00  12/2/1981 17:00 1.384415903 1981-12-02 18:00:00
7   15  10.1    12/2/1981 8:00  12/2/1981 11:00 2.293604127 1981-12-01 12:00:00
```

I want to group and rearrange above dataframe (value of column `ar`) based on following criteria:

**1. Values `latitude` and `longitude` are equal and**

**2. Values `d2` and `merge_time` are equal withing grouped in 1**

Here is desired output:

```
latitude    longitude   d1  d2  ar
15  10  12/1/1981 0:00  12/4/1981 3:00  2.317681391
15  10.1    12/1/1981 0:00  12/1/1981 22:00 4.461879893
15  10.2    12/1/1981 0:00  12/1/1981 21:00 4.379188789
15  10.3    12/1/1981 0:00  12/4/1981 2:00  2.278556423
15  10.4    12/1/1981 0:00  12/2/1981 17:00 1.384415903
15  10.1    12/2/1981 8:00  12/2/1981 11:00 2.293604127
```

How can I achieve this?
Any help is appreceated.

Comment: **d2** and **merge_time** are never equal.  What is the logic?

Comment: merge_time is created with `pd.to_datetime(df1['d2'])+datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`. Actual goal is to merge interrupted time intervals within same latitude/longitude. Interval is bordered with d1 and d2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- after expressing your requirements in comments

  - group by location (*longitude* & *latitude*)
  - find rows within this grouping that are contiguous in time
  - group and aggregate these contiguous sections

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    latitude    longitude   d1  d2  ar  merge_time
0   15  10.0    12/1/1981 0:00  12/4/1981 3:00  2.317681391  1981-12-04 04:00:00
1   15  10.1    12/1/1981 0:00  12/1/1981 3:00  2.293604127  1981-12-01 04:00:00
2   15  10.2    12/1/1981 0:00  12/1/1981 2:00  2.264552161  1981-12-01 03:00:00
3   15  10.3    12/1/1981 0:00  12/4/1981 2:00  2.278556423  1981-12-04 03:00:00
4   15  10.1    12/1/1981 4:00  12/1/1981 22:00  2.168275766  1981-12-01 23:00:00
5   15  10.2    12/1/1981 3:00  12/1/1981 21:00  2.114636628  1981-12-01 22:00:00
6   15  10.4    12/1/1981 0:00  12/2/1981 17:00  1.384415903  1981-12-02 18:00:00
7   15  10.1    12/2/1981 8:00  12/2/1981 11:00  2.293604127  1981-12-01 12:00:00"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

df = df.assign(**{c:pd.to_datetime(df[c]) for c in ["d1","d2","merge_time"]})

df.groupby(["latitude", "longitude"]).apply(
    lambda d: d.groupby(
        (d["d1"] != (d["d2"].shift() + pd.Timedelta("1H"))).cumsum(), as_index=False
    ).agg({"d1": "min", "d2": "max", "ar": "sum"})
).droplevel(2,0).reset_index()
```

#### output

|  | latitude | longitude | d1 | d2 | ar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 10 | 1981-12-01 00:00:00 | 1981-12-04 03:00:00 | 2.31768 |
| 1 | 15 | 10.1 | 1981-12-01 00:00:00 | 1981-12-01 22:00:00 | 4.46188 |
| 2 | 15 | 10.1 | 1981-12-02 08:00:00 | 1981-12-02 11:00:00 | 2.2936 |
| 3 | 15 | 10.2 | 1981-12-01 00:00:00 | 1981-12-01 21:00:00 | 4.37919 |
| 4 | 15 | 10.3 | 1981-12-01 00:00:00 | 1981-12-04 02:00:00 | 2.27856 |
| 5 | 15 | 10.4 | 1981-12-01 00:00:00 | 1981-12-02 17:00:00 | 1.38442 |